# Attribute.GetCustomAttributes() not getting my custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, reflection, custom-attributes

This is my setup, I have three projects on the solution:
Project A : class library for MVC
Project B : MVC website (main)
Project C : MVC website (area only)

C is deployed on B as an Area and that work really well. B has a reference to both A and C. C has a reference to A.

In class library A I defined the following attribute (error checking removed):

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
 public class MyAttribute : Attribute {
     public string Name = "";
     public MyAttribute(string s)
     {
         Name = s;
     }
 }
```

Then in project C (same as in project B) I have some classes where SOME methods are decorated with my custom attribute:

```
 public class SomeController : Controller, ISomethingSpecial
 {
      [MyAttribute("test")]
      public ActionResult Index() {
          return View();
      }
 }
```

The custom attribute is applied to the action methods as indicated by the attribute usage constraint.

For the sake of testing I put this code in one of the action methods of the controller:

```
IEnumerable<System.Type> all =
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<System.Reflection.Assembly>().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(type => typeof(ISomethingSpecial).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();

foreach (Type t in all) {
    if (!t.Equals(typeof(ISomethingSpecial))) {
       MyAttribute[] sea = (MyAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t, typeof(MyAttribute));
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I get to the iteration where the examined type *t* is *SomeController* which has some methods decorated with my custom attribute. But I see that the returned list of GetCustomAttributes has **zero** elements!

Before somebody asks what I basically want to achieve is obtain a list of assemblies of the web application that implement the *ISomethingSpecial* interface and from that list of candidates I want to extract the names of the methods (MVC action methods) that are decorated with my custom attribute *MyAttribute*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attribute in defined on method not on class. But in your code you request custom attributes from your class. If you need to get attributes from methods you should iterate over each method using

```
Type.GetMethods
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx

and for each method request custom attributes like you do now for your classes.

Comment: Thanks, figured that part out just a minute before but only when I viewed the local variables and that's when I noticed that I was getting zero because the class had no custom attribute. Anyway, that was the answer indeed!